What will happen when i mount several different devices on the same mountpoint?
I am learning the mount command and I am curious about what happens when I mount multiple devices to the same mount point?
#like this,what will happen?
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt

I am afraid of causing disk errors, so I dare not try

It won't break anything: any accesses would still go through the filesystem. But if you want unimportant devices to test with, you can create fs images and use the loop driver: head -c100M /dev/zero > testfs.bin; mkfs testfs.bin; mount -oloop testfs.bin /mnt etc.

Generally what will happen is that only the most recently mounted partition will be visible at /mnt, with each successive mounting "masking" what was originally there.  So in your example you would see the contents of /dev/sdb1.
Experimentation on this is a viable thing to do if you do so with disks you don't care about data loss on, or less (potentially) destructively with virtual drives in a virtualized environment such as VirtualBox or QEMU/KVM.
